# Difficulty Executing .jar file via python on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7, subprocess, executable-jar

I am having some difficulty getting python to execute a .jar file via windows 7 command line. My code is as follows:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'file.jar'], shell = True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

When I run this code, nothing happens. I have tried executing

```
java -jar file.jar
```

into the command prompt directly and the .jar application opens and runs normally.

I have also tried replacing it with Popen

```
subprocess.Popen(['java', '-jar', 'file.jar'], shell = True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

And have tried other ways as well

```
subprocess.call(['cmd','\C type java -jar file.jar'], shell = True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

and

```
import os
os.system('java -jar file.jar')
```

All of these do not do anything.

I tried running another command line

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['ipconfig'])
```

and this worked just fine. Also,

```
subprocess.call(['java -jar file.jar'])
```

worked just fine when I ran it on my mac.

Any idea what the problem could be? I would really appreciate any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here:

- Especify the class name that contains the main() method

> java -jar JarFile.jar com.something.TheClass

- Add a MANIFEST.MF file to the jar that has the name of the class that contains the main() method.

> ```
> Manifest-version: 1.0
> Main-Class: com.something.TheClass
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I appreciate your advice. I tried the first option and specified the main class. It worked when put into command prompt directly, but not within the python script (like before). For the manifest file. Does this two line file go in the directory of the .jar file or one of the subfolders?